# Can I apply for a Schengen business visa from other country where I went for tourism?

Tags: visas, schengen, long-stay-visas

If I am a citizen of country A and I went for tourism to country B. Means I am not there for long stay or have temporary residence, student or work purposes but short stay just for tourism. So can I apply a Schengen visa for business purposes from country B or I must apply from country A where I'm citizen?

Please don't duplicate my question with this question [link](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72391/can-i-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-at-a-country-where-im-not-a-citizen-if-so-und) I am not asking this.

Comment: That linked question certainly looks like it's a duplicate to me. The only way I see that it wouldn't be a duplicate is if you name countries A, B, and the Schengen countries you want to visit.

Comment: Context is different. I am asking different, countries A,B are just examples.

Comment: Please explain how your question differs from the one you claim it is not a duplicate of. Sure looks like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @ShanXeeshi the question that you claim isn't a duplicate is *also* expressed in general terms as country A and country B.  How is the context different?