# As foreigner, can I get my Bolivian visa in Brazil?

Tags: visas, brazil, embassies, bolivia

I am looking to apply for the Bolivian visa in Brazil, as a foreigner, but I have no idea what the process is like, how long it is and where I can find information about it...

In my country (Romania), Bolivia does not have an embassy. The closest one is Berlin, and I have a friend that send the documents via DHL to Berlin and waited to get them and eventually she got the visa.

But I am already in Brazil, and I am wondering if this makes it easier for me to get the Bolivian visa. I speak Spanish and I am good enough in speaking Portuguese too.

I have not called the embassy yet (will probably do), but I would like to have a general idea about this (if it's possible, what the process is like etc).

What are the steps to get my Bolivian visa, in Brazil, as a foreigner?

Comment: Where are you in Brazil and what is your immigration status there? http://www.consuladodeboliviaenrio.org.br/visas.php

Comment: As far as I know it generally makes no difference to the foreign embassy in a particular country if you are either a national, resident or only a vistor to that country.  From a practical perspective there may be some considerations for travellers though: can you be without your passport for however long the foreign embassy needs it for processing, can you supply all required documentation and/or can the foreign embassy accept such documents in their original language or do you need to get them translated? (It seems unlikely that in Brazil they will speak Romanian in the Bolivian embassy)

Comment: @HBruijn If it is a matter of days/weeks perhaps I can wait... The documents have the English translations too.

Comment: @HBruijn I don’t know whether it applies to Brazil but is not at all uncommon for countries to require applications to be made from the applicant’s country of residence eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72391/can-i-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-at-a-country-where-im-not-a-citizen-if-so-und

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called the Embassy of Bolivia in Sao Paulo and they confirmed getting a Bolivian visa would take around 24 hours if all the documents are the documents are provided and the process goes well.

However, due to the conflicts in Bolivia I decided not to go.