# Can a refugee visiting one Schengen country visa-free apply for a visa to other Schengen countries, while already in one of the EU countries?

Tags: schengen-visas, applications, refugees, us-residents

I have a US Asylee/Refugee Travel Document. This allows me to travel to a few countries within the Schengen area without a visa requirement.

I traveled to Amsterdam and Belgium two years ago using my travel document and visa free. I am going to visit Belgium again in less than a month, and, while there, I would like to visit Italy for two days for a concert. How would that work? Is there a way for me to apply for a Schengen Visa while I am already in one of the Schengen Countries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I apply for a Schengen visa at a country where I'm not a citizen? If so, under what conditions?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72391/can-i-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-at-a-country-where-im-not-a-citizen-if-so-und)

Comment: If this question is closed I would suggest editing it to ask "how do I manage the requirement to get a visa for this itinerary," which is not a duplicate of the other question, and for which you already have a good answer.  If that happens, ping me and I will vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Most universally, you can only apply for a visa at an embassy or consulate located in your country of residence. I have not checked the individual rules of every single Schengen country, but I'd image they all apply this rule.

So no, you probably can't obtain a visa for Italy while already in Europe. You'd have to do this in the US before heading off.

Of course, there are usually no border controls inside the Schengen zone. Not that I'd recommend breaking the law, but most probably nobody will stop you or even care if you just take a train or bus to Italy and back.

Comment: You don't have to check each country; the rule is specified in the Schengen Visa Code.  The thing that is likely to vary from one country to another is the availability of the exceptions that are also specified in the code; questions here imply that some visa application systems fail to make available any way for an applicant to invoke these exceptions.  Also a two-day trip implies flying, and I have no idea whether any airlines would do a visa check for an internal Schengen flight, but I wouldn't rule it out.  But the real answer here is "get the visa in the US," so +1 from me,

Comment: Thank you for your response, guys! Much appreciated!